# Angular Material 2 mat-palette() using lighter and darker option

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

Based on the [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) you can define a custom theme `accent` for our example. The second parameter will override the `$mat-pink` default to A200, but how does the 3rd (`$lighter`) and 4th (`$darker`) parameter works?

`$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);`

> From `@angular/material/_theming.scss`
>
> ```
> @function mat-palette($base-palette, $default: 500, $lighter: 100, $darker: 700) {
>    .....
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those different hues are used by a few components, such as the progress bar. But it's more useful if you're using them as mixins for your own styling. [This answer on a GH issue gives a good explanation](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4297#issuecomment-298630685).

Comment: thanks for the link! it would really be nice if there something like md-colors="{}" or a class like md-hue-2 etc, however it is currently not possible until they use css variables. So this is still the early stage of the angular-material2 development i think :)